Postgresql is not accepting datetime format from CSV file
I am trying to load a CSV file to my PGadmin database (on my local computer). I am running PostgreSQL16 with PGadmin4 as the user interface. I am trying to upload the date data as follows:



UniqueID
Date




1
25/01/2023  00:00:00


2
14/07/2014  00:00:00



I have set the date column to be a timestamp without a timezone. When I run this script to import the csv file:
\copy public.mytable (UniqueID, Date) FROM 'Directory/Filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""

I get the following error message:
ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "26/01/2020 00:00"
HINT: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT: COPY salespeople, line 2, column hire_date: "26/01/2020 00:00"
I have tried the following commands:
SET DateStyle TO ISO, DMY;
SHOW DateStyle;

To see the current datestyle in my database and then adapt the datestyle formatting as needed but I can't quite figure out how to make this work. I've tried setting the datestyle to 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm:ss' but this code is not recognised.
How can I change the datestyle in my database so that the format of the CSV file is accepted?

Inspired by an answer in this post Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting I have decided to change the formatting of the dates in my CSV file to match PostgreSQL's standard date formats, i.e. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and this has resolved the issue.
This is not the most robust solution - if you subsequently open the csv file and do not reset the formatting, then it will not work. But it does the job.
